# How can I load data to existing tsql table from c# arraylist?

Tags: c#, t-sql, arraylist

I have data in a arraylist that is organized with 19 fields.  How do I load to the sql table?  Some advice I revcieved was to write a sproc then call the sproc is C#, but I need to know what the sproc looks like.  Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches, one of them is to call the stored proc n times passing an array member every time, at sql side you can store records in a temporal table and once you send the last record persist all records to the permanent table.

The SP would look like

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP (
>  @field1 varchar(10), 
>  ...
>  @fieldN  varchar(),
>  @IstheLastRecord bit = 0,)
>
>  INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
> (field1, ... fieldN)
> VALUES @field1,...@fieldN
>
>  IF  @IstheLastRecord=1
> BEGIN
>   INSERT INTO PERM_TABLE
>   SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE
>   TRUNCATE TEMP_TABLE
> END
> ```

Another and more efficient approach is to convert the array into an xml object in c# and pass a xml typed parameter to the store procedure, the store procedure looks like

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP (
     @arraydata xml
 )
 AS 

INSERT INTO dbo.Perm_TABLE(field1,..., fieldN)
  SELECT
    Rec.value('(field1)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'field1',
    ...
    Rec.value('(fieldN)[1]', 'Varchar(50)') as 'fieldN',
  FROM
   @arraydata.nodes('/rootelement/records') as Root(Rec)
```

the xml object wuld look like

```
   <Root>
        <Record> 
            <field1>Value field1</field1>
            ...
            <fieldN>Value fieldN</fieldN>
        </Record>
        <Record> 
            <field1>Value field1</field1>
            ...
            <fieldN>Value fieldN</fieldN>
        </Record>
        ....

   </Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic CRUD operation, you can write an INSERT stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spINSERT_dbo_Customer @FirstName varchar(25), @LastName varchar(100)

    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer]
               ([FirstName]
               ,[LastName])
    VALUES (@FirstName
           ,@LastName)
    GO
```

However! If you have many rows to insert at once there is a much more efficient way of doing this without using a stored procedure, take a look at this blog post, he explains it very clearly:

http://yassershaikh.com/sqlbulkcopy-bulk-insert-using-sqlbulkcopy-with-c-asp-net/

Answer (score 0):

I realized an Arraylist is not great for what I was trying to do.  The better way was using a DataTable and defining the columns and rows.  Use StreamReader to read thru each line then use substring to define each data field.  Then use sqlbulk insert to put into sql table.

```c#
public void ImportToSql(string file path, string connectionStr)
{
  var dt = new DataTable("TableName");
  dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
  dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
  using(var reader = new StreamReader(FilePath))
{
while(!reader.EndOfStream)
{
  string line = reader.ReadLine();
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))Continue;
  string field1 = line.substring(0,9);
  string field2 = line.substring(9,9);
  var row = dt.NewRow();
  row["Column1"] = field1.Trim();
  row["Column2"] = field2.Trim();
  dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
using(var conn = new sqlconnection(connectionStr)
{
  connectionStr.Open();
  using(var blkCopy = new SqlBulkCooy(connectionStr)
{
  blkcopy.DestinationTableName = "Table1";
  blkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
}
}
}
}
```